# Electron and React.js: How to load local resource

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-packager

I want to create Electron executable and supporting files for distribution with React but got an error, Not allowed to load local resource.

Here are the relevant entries in my `package.json`

```
{
   "productName": "Test system",
   "homepage": "./",
   "main": "main.js",
   "scripts": {
      "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    }
}
```

Here is createWindow method, in `main.js`

```
function createWindow() {
    // Initialize the window to our specified dimensions
    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000, height: 600 });

    // Show dev tools[enter image description here][1]
    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Specify entry point
    win.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:8080' : `file://${path.join(__dirname+'build/index.html')}`);

    // Remove window once app is closed
    win.on('closed', function () {
        win = null;
    });
}
```